# How to makes two actions at once time with javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

My Element:

```
<p id="someid"> 1 word , 2 words, one word, two words.</p>
```

My script:

```
var doc = document.getElementById("someid").innerHTML;
var x = ["1 word", "2 words"];
var y = ["one word", "two words"];

for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    var a = x[i];
    var b = y[i];
    var c = "\\b"+a+"\\b";
    var d = new RegExp(c,'gi');
    doc = doc.replace(d, b); 
}
document.getElementById("someid").innerHTML = doc;
```

Result:

> <p id="someid"> one word, two words, one word, two words.</p>

But I want to change it to:

> <p id="someid"> one word, two words, 1 word, 2 words.</p>

What should I do to make it?

Comment: This cant be done using regex.. i think.. you should split the words (by comma?) and for each word if it is in `array x` replace with word in `array y` else if it is in `array y`.. replace with corresponding word in `array x`..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code just replaces any match with `a` to corresponding `b`, but you'll need a few changes to make it two-way:

```
var c = "(\\b"+a+"\\b)|(\\b"+b+"\\b)";
var d = new RegExp(c,'gi');
doc = doc.replace(d, function (match, p1) {
    return p1 ? b : a;
});
```

So it matches `a` with corresponding `b` and vice versa.

[**jsfiddle DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/samuraii/vp0n84cu/)

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I try the code that you provide and that,s Works. Thanks